# Every set with more than $k$ elements is dependent

Tags: ring-theory, modules

> If $F$ is a free $R-$module, $R$ a domain, with rank=$k$ and $X\subset F$ show that $X$ is linear independent $\Rightarrow |X|\leq k$

There is a hint saying "consider the embedding of $R$ in it's field of fractions $R'$"

**Attempt**

Let $\phi:R\to R'$ be this embedding and $X\subset F$ with $|X|>k,X=\{x_1,...,x_m\}$

We may consider $F$ as a $R'-$module ($*$) so $R'-$ vector space and then since $dim_{R'}F=k$, $X$ is linear dependent over $R'$. Then I showed that $X$ is linear dependent over $R$.

So my question is :

How can I justify $(*)$ (if it is true)?? Is there a quicker way to answer this exercise??

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A priori you can only view F as an R-module.
However,
the span of the image under a linear extension of the embedding can be viewed as a free module over the field of fractions. I.e. as a vector space over the field of fractions.

The nice thing is, that the embedding preserves the property of being linearly independent over R. Now the only thing you need to prove is that linear independence over R implies linear independence over R’  when R is a domain (multiply by every denominator in the R’ linear combination).

I hope this helps.

Comment: when you say "the span of the image under the embedding can be viewed as a free module over the field of fractions" do you mean that $\phi(R)$ is $R'-$module? How is this related to $F$?

Comment: Oh, sorry i thought the embedding in question was the linear extension of $\phi$ from F to the free R’ module with k generators (just take the same generators) I can see why this is a cause of confusion.

Comment: I'm sorry but I still can't understand your answer

Comment: Whenever you have a ring homomorphism say $\Phi : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R’}$ it extends to a “linear” map between finitely generated modules: $\tilde{\Phi} : F \to F’ $ defined by mapping generators to generators and scalar multiplication by r to scalar multiplication by $\Phi (r)$.

Comment: I have $F$,what is $F'$??

Comment: In your case F is the free rank k R module with generators v1,...,vk and F’ is a free rank k R’ module with generators say w1,...,wk. Then your map $\tilde{\Phi}$ should be the linear map that maps vi to wi and r*vi to Phi(r)*wi.

Comment: So what you say is $F$ is free with generators $\{v_1,...,v_k\}$ ,$\Phi(F)=F'$ a free $R'-$module with generators $\{w_1,...,w_k\}$, where $\phi:R\to R'$ is the embedding  and $\Phi: F\to F':\Phi(v_i)=w_i,\Phi(rv_i)=\phi(r)m_i$  ??

Comment: Could you explain why all these are well defined?

Comment: Well, \Phi (F) is not all of F’, however, R’ linear combinations of \Phi(F) is. I am not sure what you believe  is Il defined? By the way, it should be w_i not m_i

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't follow you. Could you explain your answer in detail?

Comment: Sure i can make it more explicit.

Comment: The injective homomorphism of rings (embedding) $\phi\colon R \to R'$ given by $r\mapsto \frac{r}{1}$, extends to a map $\Phi \colon F \to F'$ given by $\Phi(\sum_{i=1}^k r_iv_i)=\sum_{i=1}^k \phi(r_i)w_i$. This map is clearly additive and preserves linear R-independence.

Comment: I see. So $\Phi $ apart from being  additive and preserving linear $R$-independence it also makes $F'$ a $R'-$module?

Comment: i.e. it maps a set of R-linearly independent elements to $\phi(R)$-linear independent vectors in the $R'$ vector space $F'$. 

Now $\Phi(F)$ is in and of itself not a vector subspace of $F'$ since it is not closed under scalar multiplication by $R'$. However the set of all $R'$ linear combinations of $\Phi(F)$ is subspace of $F'$ (in fact it is all of $F'$). Now suppose we have a $R$-linearly independent subset $X\subset F$ then $\Phi(X)$ is an $R$-linearly independent subset of $F'$. It remains to prove that $R$-linear independence in $F'$ implies $R'$-linear independence.

Comment: This can be shown quite easily. Suppose $x_1,\dots,x_n$ is a collection of $R$-linear independent elements in $F'$ then:
$$0=\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{p_i}{q_i}x_i \implies 0=0\cdot q_1\cdot \dots q_n=\sum_{i=1}^n p_i\cdot q_1\cdot \dots \hat{\q_i} \dots \cdot q_n x_i $$
Where $\hat{q_i}$ means omitted from the product. The last equation + $\phi(R)$-indpendence then implies $p_i\cdot q_1\cdot \dots \hat{\q_i} \dots \cdot q_n=0$ for any $i$. Since $R$ is a domain $p_i=0$ and thus $\frac{p_i}{q_i}=0$ in $R'$

Comment: ok I think I got it! Thank you very much!

Comment: Sure, but it does not have to be the lcm since the lcm does not necessarily exist in arbitrary rings.

Comment: you're right  !!

Comment: I am happy that i could help. Sorry for the confusion!

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you could consider the tensor product 
$$F':=F\otimes_R R',$$
which is a vector space over $R'$.

A linear $R$-combination in $F$
$$r_1a_1+\cdots + r_na_n=0,$$
$a_i\in F, r_i\in R$ with some $r_j\neq0$, lifts to a linear $R$-combination in $F'$
$$r_1(a_1\otimes 1)+\cdots + r_n(a_n\otimes 1)=0,$$
which is clearly also a linear $R'$-combination with some $r_j\neq0$.

Reciprocally, any linear $R'$-combination in $F'$ of the form
$$q_1(a_1\otimes 1)+\cdots + q_n(a_n\otimes 1)=0,$$
$a_i\in F, q_i\in R'$, $q_i=r_i/s_i$ with some $q_j\neq0$, gives a linear combination 
$$r_1(a_1\otimes 1)+\cdots + r_n(a_n\otimes 1)=0,$$
where $r_i=sq_i\in R$, with $s=s_1\cdots s_n$, so with $r_j\neq0$, which in turn projects to a linear combination
$$r_1a_1+\cdots + r_na_n=0$$
in $R$ with some $r_j\neq0$.

These two facts together prove that a basis for $F$ gives a basis for $F'$ of the same cardinal, that all bases for $F$ have the same cardinal (since $F'$ is a vector space), that the rank of the $F$-module is indeed well defined, and that any set of more than rank$(F)$ vectors in $F$ must be linearly dependent (otherwise, it would generate an independent set in $F'$ with more vectors than $\dim_{R'} F'$, a contradiction).

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't know about tensor products

Comment: @giannispapav Tensor products are pretty interesting. They can be a bit difficult to comprehend, but they are very useful (in part because what they convey is not that intuitive, so thinking about them sometimes opens new paths). You ought to learn them well when the time is due!